# EnvDTE VS 2012 Create a physical folder in an existing folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte

How can you create a folder in a solution project inside an already existing physical folder with `EnvDTE`?

project
  - folder
    - create this folder

Answer (score 0):

This works for C++ project in VS2012. For other project types you might need to use physical folder, not sure.
The code assumes you've got "First Level Folder" folder in your project already.

```
Project project = null; // you should get the project from the solution or as active project or somehow else
ProjectItem folderItem = project.ProjectItems.Item("First Level Folder");
folderItem.ProjectItems.AddFolder("Second Level Folder", Constants.vsProjectItemKindVirtualFolder);
```

Note that the code might not compile and run properly, it is just a snippet.